# How do you rename a filename in Sharepoint META data using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, api, sharepoint

I am working with Sharepoint and trying to create functionality to rename a file using a form field in a modal. How do I go about doing this using JQuery? I've working on this issue for 5 hours with no success nothing seems to work. MoveTo is not an option because of the URL limits. We don't have access to the config file to increase the length.I also cannot using any endpoints that require a library name because of the issue with "&" ['ampersands].

I've tried various endpoints, used ajax, tried changing Name entry in the API, I tried fileLeafRef, I've tried everything I can think. I need something solid. I only get an error with permission 403. I'm assuming this means my URL is fine and it's something else not being added to the code.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

just ended up using MoveTo because using the META data was not going to work for all users of Sharepoint [due to permissions].